# Get inputted data separated & post different data in different containers

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to build a page that is supposed to show user-posted news in different columns? spereated by `<divs>`. What I want to do is to receive data from my database and separate it so that the first data that is located in for example the Headline attribute gets posted in the first H3 column and the second data also located in the Headline attribute gets posted in the second H3 column. I have solved the connection to the database and the ability to post to it with PHP but have no idea how to solve this part where I just want the data to show up.

The database got just one table:
Table:

- NEWS

Attributes:

- News_ID
- Headline
- Content

sudocode: `<div class="col1"><H3> <?php Headline = first post ?> </H3> <p><?php Content = first post ?></div> <div class="col2"><H3> <?php Headline = second post ?> </H3> <p><?php Content = second post ?></div>`

and so on. with a limit to always show the last six news posted. I hope that you guys understand what I try to accomplish.

Comment: What you've written is NOT php. `<?php Headline = first post ?>` this is not a valid php code.

Comment: Sudo (Superuser do) and Pseudo (Greek) are not the same thing.

Comment: Easy: `fetch data from DB` -> `loop through data with foreach` -> `echo out div with relevant data` -> `maximum profits.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you use MySQL as your database and are also using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). If you're not, I recommend you get familiar with PDO.
First of all, you obviously need to fetch the information (the news) from the database:

```
$sql = "SELECT News_ID, Headline, Content from NEWS ORDER BY News_ID DESC LIMIT 0,6";
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql); // $pdo is your "connection" to the database
$statement->execute();
$news = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // $news array now has the six latest rows from your NEWS table
```

Then loop over the news:

```
foreach($news as $news_item) { // foreach will go through each element in the $news array
  echo "<div class='something'>";
    echo "<h3>".$news_item['Headline']."</h3>";
    echo $news_item['Content'];
  echo "</div>";
}
```

I edited the SQL so that it returns you the results you want, which is the six latest records in your NEWS table. I strongly recommend you just use `foreach` to loop over the `$news` array, as it only has those six latest rows you're after. No need to do `echo $news[0]['Content']` for each of your rows.

If my answer helped you do what you wanted, you can accept it.

Comment: Okey, I found an other way to almost solve my problem, but thank you for taking the time to help. This Answer gave me a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Okey I have soved my question "almost"

```
<?php
$user_name  = "root";
$password   = "";
$database   = "Hemsida";
$server     = "localhost";



try{
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$server.'; dbname='.$database.';' , $user_name, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}


try{
    $result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `News`");
    $result->execute();
    $news = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

and in every `<div>` I just add `<?php echo $news[0][Headline] ?>` where I just have to change the number in the `[0]` for each different column. Although I still got one problem. This will only show the six first posts that are made and not the six last posts, is there something you can do to reverse so that It grabs the last Post first so that the last post gets assigned `[0]` instead?